# how to import openssl/sha.h or openssl/md5.h on macOS

Tags: c++, c, macos, openssl, homebrew

I'm trying to import openssl header into my cpp file on macos like this :

```sh
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
```

I try to install openssl with :

```sh
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```

then I got this:

```
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@3
If you need to have openssl@3 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@3 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include"
```

so I run :

```sh
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
```

to run my file I use  `g++ -lcrypto -lssl main.cpp -o main && ./main`

but I got all this warning and library not found :

```
main.cpp:14:3: warning: 'MD5' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  MD5((unsigned char*)s, strlen(s), empreinte);
  ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/md5.h:52:1: note: 'MD5' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 unsigned char *MD5(const unsigned char *d, size_t n,
^
/usr/local/include/openssl/macros.h:182:49: note: expanded from macro 'OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0'
#   define OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0                OSSL_DEPRECATED(3.0)
                                                ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/macros.h:62:52: note: expanded from macro 'OSSL_DEPRECATED'
#     define OSSL_DEPRECATED(since) __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                   ^
1 warning generated.
ld: library not found for -lcrypto
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Please replace those images with the text they contain. That allows searching for the error messages, which is what you should have done before even posting here.